# Perl DBI/DBD error message contains strange characters

Tags: linux, perl, dbi

I have recently come across the following behaviour and wondered if there was a fix.

I have a Linux perl (V5.16.3) program that connects to an Oracle database (V11g2) using DBI.

The program captures any errors generated by the database in a file (re-direction of STDERR). It should be noted that the same behaviour occurs if STDERR is written to the console instead of a file.

As far as I am aware all my information is in UTF-8. However, if the error message generated by DBI/DBD contains, for example, the character `é` then this character is represented as `Ã©` in the DBI error message.

Is it possible to generate the error message without any of these strange characters? I need to be able to generate error files that can be interpreted by whoever is analysing them.

Here is the code with the 'deliberate' error in order to generate the DBI error message containing the strange character:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use DBI ;
use DBD::Oracle ;
$ENV{'ORACLE_HOME'} = "/home/ora11g2" ;
$ENV{'NLS_LANG'} = "french_france.AL32UTF8" ;
$ENV{'LANG'} = "fr_FR.utf-8" ;

binmode(STDOUT, ':utf8');
binmode(STDERR, ":utf8");

my $STDERR_File='/home/error_files/DBIerrorfile.log';
open STDERR, '>' . $STDERR_File;

my $SRV='abc';
my $DB='db1';
my $idficval=1;


my %attr = (PrintError => 1,RaiseError => 1,ora_charset => 'AL32UTF8');
my $db = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:$SRV/$DB", "user", "pword", \%attr )  or die "impossible de se connecter à $SRV / $DB";
$db->{AutoCommit} = 0 ;


my $Info="select value from vals_tableé where idval>?";
my $Info_sth = $db->prepare($Info);
$Info_sth->execute($idficval);

my @rowP1;
my @Info;
while (@rowP1 = $Info_sth->fetchrow_array) {  # retrieve one row
    print $rowP1[0] . "\n"
}
$db->disconnect if defined($db);
```

The error message generated is:

> DBD::Oracle::db prepare failed: ORA-00942: Table ou vue inexistante
> (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 21 in 'select
> value from <*>vals_tableÃ© where idval>:p1') [for Statement "select
> value from vals_tableÃ© where idval>?"]

Comment: The messages are encoded using UTF-8. Your binmode is re-applying UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami, commenting out `binmode(STDERR, ":utf8");` did the trick. Unfortunately I need to capture all sorts of possible errors in my program, of which the code above is a very small part. So removing `binmode(STDERR, ":utf8");` now causes strange characters with other errors!

Comment: So fix the other half: Decode the errors from the DB instead.